# How to get even key value from array in PHP without using any loop

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I have an array with values starting from **1 to 10000**

```
$a= array(1,2,....,10000);
```

I want even key values without using any loops, how it is possible?

Comment: Why do you want it without a loop?

Comment: what you try for it?

Comment: You must have tries something, right?

Comment: You want the even keys or the even values?

Comment: I have been asked in interview and I didn't have idea.I have done googling for  it but not find search satisfied result

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could look at using [array_filter()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php).

I modified the below from that exact page;

```
<?php
function even($var) {
    return(!($var & 1));
}

$array = array(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10);

print_r(array_filter($array, "even"));
?>
```

Comment: Great ! Can you please explain it what is  return(!($var & 1));

Comment: Sure. The `&` operator is known as the `bitwise and`(http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php) operator. This compares each bit and checks that they are equal. In the above example, if `$var` is  `2`, it will have the binary value of `00000010`. `1` will have the binary value of `00000001`. The `&` operator will go through each bit(`1` or `0`) and check for equality. Since the `1` bit in `00000010`(2) is not set, `(2 & 1)` will return `0` since the test `1 === 0` will fail for that bit. To compensate for this, the function does a `not` or `!` to flip that to a `1`(true).

Answer (score 1):

Another weird way:

```
$a = range(1, 10000); // initial
$b = range(1, 10000, 2); // odd
$c = array_diff($a, $b); // even
```

Answer (score 1):

I like Ghost's answer so I was thinking how to modify it in case you really wanted **even keys** and not even values:

```
<?php

$values = range(1, 10000); // initial values
$keys = range(0, (count($values) - 1), 2); // even keys as array values
$keys = array_flip($keys); // even keys as array keys
$result = array_intersect_key($values, $keys); // intersection based on keys
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [array_filter](http://php.net/array_filter) with `range(1,10000)` to generate array,

```
$even=array_filter(range(1,10000),
                   function ($input) {
                       return !($input & 1);
                   });
echo '<pre>';
print_r($even);
echo '</pre>';
```